# Do C# collections always enforce order?

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I.E. If I want to select from an array, is the resultant `IEnumerable<object>` object necessarily in order?

```
public class Student { public string FullName, ... }
public class School { public string Name, public Student[] Students, ... }

public void StudentListWork(School thisSchool)
{
    IEnumerable<string> StudentNames = thisSchool.Students.Select(student => student.FullName);

    // IS StudentNames GUARANTEED TO BE IN THE SAME ORDER AS thisSchool.Students?
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is Students?  A list?  a sorted list?  an array? a dictionary?  "collections" is a broad term, and they have different characteristics.

Comment: @Mystere: As per the second line, it's an array.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - Doh! missed that...

Comment: IEnumerable implementations of ordered collections do not go out of their way to return items in an un-ordered sequence.  Not guaranteed, just horse sense.  You can take a dependency on that, it won't be broken.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, in *this* case:

- Arrays returns items in the natural order
- [`Enumerable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) returns items in the order of the original sequence (after projection, of course)

Some collections do *not* retain order, however. In particular:

- Collections such as `HashSet<T>` and `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` make no guarantees about the order in which values are returned
- Collections such as `SortedSet<T>` and `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>` apply guaranteed ordering based on the items placed within them